# What is the array for Excel "control shift home" or all active cells with data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, pivot-table

I am NOT a programmer, but sometimes I play one in my job - Kind of ;)

Example:  I recorded a VBA macro to un-pivot data (some people call this a reverse pivot or flatting a database or something like that).  My columns and rows can vary from 1000 by 500 to 8,000 by 5,000. 
 Each file may vary (I won't know the number of rows or columns).  When I set the range for my pivot table larger than the actual data, I get a number rows with totally meaningless data.

How do set the pivot table range (array???) to select all the rows and columns with data? 
When I recorded a macro to do select everything (control shift home), this what I get:

```
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

Buy I cannot get this to work in the array that the pivot table needs.

```
Array("Sheet2!R1C1:R15C25"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable12", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion14
```

I appreciate your help. Keep in mind that I not a programmer so please use simple words and explanations! Thanks!

Comment: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` will return a range which includes all *contiguous* rows and columns: same as pressing Ctrl+A

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  And I learned a new keyboard short cut.  How do I get that inside the Array that the VBS needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set rngSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngDest = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                    SourceData:=rngSrc, _
                    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=rngDest, TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tim.  I'm getting this error:  The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable Report you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. BTW - I do have labeld columns.

Comment: I get that if (eg) A1 isn't actually part of the table you want to create the pivot from (eg if the top-left of my source data is at A2).  Make sure to adjust that code so you start off *within the source data* when setting `rngSrc`.

Comment: Now I'm getting a Run-time error '1004' Application - defined or object . . .  Then I closed everything and reopened the file and I get another '1004' Application - Unable to get the Pivot Table property of the worksheet class.. .   What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing (right *or* wrong!) without seeing any of your code.  You can update your question to add the current version.

Comment: So I commented out some extra code that I added and it almost runs!  It stops with the Pivot Table Filed list on sheet 2, but no pivot table.

Comment: Why won't this work??Dim rngSrc As Range

Set rngSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
   

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, _
        SourceData:=rngSrc, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable14", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14
    ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable14").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
        "Count of Value").Position = 1
End Sub